# How to pass python json.dump() to print in <p> </p> in html?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I this simple scenario I am trying to create and dump a json string via python then parse the json dump and print it via html.

python:

```
import json

pythonDictionary = {'name':'Bob', 'age':44, 'isEmployed':True}
dictionaryToJson = json.dumps(pythonDictionary)
```

html & js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h1>My First Heading</h1>
 <p id="messages"></p>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

    <script>

        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = dictionaryToJson;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with using CGI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `python-shell` like the following

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell("code.py");

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = message;
});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    };

    console.log('finished');
});
```

I am assuming `code.py` contains the python codes

```
import json
pythonDictionary = {'name':'Bob', 'age':44, 'isEmployed':True}
dictionaryToJson = json.dumps(pythonDictionary)
print(dictionaryToJson )
```